# Informatica MDM - Repository Manager Import Change list - Batch Group error c360

Tags: java, exception, repository, informatica, mdm

i had succed installing the MDM Information Hub + ActiveVos (10.2 MDM on Jboss 6.4 Oracle 12, os Red Hat)

I start the installation of the C360.

As the first step it says to go on **Repository Manager > Import > change-list.xml**

When the change list it's loaded i got the following error

> Object 'RESOURCE.BATCH_GROUP.BATCH_GROUP' already exists. Object
> cannot be added.
> (addSecureResource[id:RESOURCE.BATCH_GROUP.BATCH_GROUP]). Cannot
> create the source repository.

I try to first validate (success) - activate the Hierarchy Manager - promote the change list (same error).

Also there is more error like this

> ERROR com.siperian.mrm.repository.beans.schema.XsdRepositoryLoader -
> Can't generate CO ORS schema. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't
> find type {urn:co-ors.informatica.mdm}LookupCountry.LookupState
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find type
> {urn:co-ors.informatica.mdm}OrganizationSubsidiaryRelatedOrg
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find type
> {urn:co-ors.informatica.mdm}PersonGuardianPerson
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find type
> {urn:co-ors.informatica.mdm}PersonChildPerson
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find type
> {urn:co-ors.informatica.mdm}LookupCountry.LookupState
>
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't find type
> {urn:co-ors.informatica.mdm}CustomerOrg

What it could be?
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Regards.

Tell me which info i can provide.

Console.log file at [Google drive link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4vucTdGZxJkT01ZSlN6NHltbnM)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was due to Informatica C360 with no compatibility on Informatica MDM 10.2 HF1.